# Cursor: pointer not working on pseudo elements + how to add link to a HTML button with icon?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add social buttons to my website with simple HTML and a few lines of CSS.

Here's what I came up with:

```
<button class="facebook-btn"><span class="dashicons dashicons-facebook-alt"></span></button>
<button class="twitter-btn"><span class="dashicons dashicons-twitter"  ></span></button>
```

```
.facebook-btn, .twitter-btn{
    height:105px;
    width:50% !important;
    float:left !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.facebook-btn{
    background: #405992;
}

.twitter-btn{
    background: #4099ff;
}

.custom-html-widget .facebook-btn span, .twitter-btn span{
    font-size:48px;
    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    top:-27px;
}

.custom-html-widget .facebook-btn span:after{
    font-family: Barlow;
    position: relative;
    top:7px !important;
    content: "Polub";
    font-size:18px !important;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.custom-html-widget .twitter-btn span:after{
    font-family: Barlow;
    position: relative;
    top:7px !important;
    content: "Zaobserwuj";
    font-size:18px !important;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.facebook-btn:hover, .twitter-btn:hover {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0t17mv5x/ (JSFiddle can't load Dashicons, so icons are not visible, but here's how it looks on my site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO7Qi.jpg).

I have one question and one problem.

1. How can I add links to these buttons without visible anchors? I want to be able to click on a Facebook or Twitter icon and be redirected to my site's fan page.
2. I need to add cursor: pointer to pseudo-elements in my code, but I have no idea how. It works outside of pseudo-elements (Dashicons and text in this scenario), but not on the pseudo-elements themselves. Once again, JsFiddle can't load Dashicons so here it works fine, but not on my site.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the fiddle you didn't add a `div.custom-html-widget` outside the two buttons. Also, the cursor property in  the css of your pseudo elements works when I try it in the fiddle you gave.

Comment: Yeah, it works in the fiddle because JSFiddle can't load Wordpress Dashicons. Please check this screenshot - this is how it looks when Dashicons are properly loaded:  https://i.imgur.com/5XHpWkM.jpg

Comment: Hi, I can't totally understand your fiddle code. Where does .custom-html-widget come into it? Also, is there a reason for not just using anchor tags instead of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your `a tag` around the buttons with your fan page's URL linked to each respective button. This [link](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) is really helpful when referring to social media icons or buttons. Using the bootstrap class `btn-facebook` in this case is the way to do it. There are also ways to do it inline also such as using the `#3B5998` code.

```css
.facebook-btn, .twitter-btn{
    height:105px;
    width:50% !important;
    float:left !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.facebook-btn{
    background: #405992;
}

.twitter-btn{
    background: #4099ff;
}

.custom-html-widget .facebook-btn span, .twitter-btn span{
    font-size:48px;
    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    top:-27px;
}

.custom-html-widget .facebook-btn span:after{
    font-family: Barlow;
    position: relative;
    top:7px !important;
    content: "Polub";
    font-size:18px !important;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.custom-html-widget .twitter-btn span:after{
    font-family: Barlow;
    position: relative;
    top:7px !important;
    content: "Zaobserwuj";
    font-size:18px !important;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.facebook-btn:hover, .twitter-btn:hover {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer; /* added to hover effect, seemed to be working fine in fiddle */
}
```

```html
<a href="facebookURL.com"><button class="facebook-btn"><span class="dashicons dashicons-facebook-alt"></span></button></a>
<a href="twitterURL.com"><button class="twitter-btn"><span class="dashicons dashicons-twitter"></span></button></a>
```

Comment: Try adding `cursor: pointer;` to your CSS class called `.widget-area` It seems your `.widget-area` class contains both social media icons / images (Stay in touch & the SO section). If you don't want to have the cursor turn to pointer on white space I would recommend making both of the widget areas it's own container with it's own class. For example make the top portion that is focus right now called `.widget-area-top`

Comment: It's not a perfect solution because it indeed adds a cursor over the area, but only small part of the buttons is a clickable link. You need to click at the very top of each button to be redirected to Facebook or Twitter. The whole button needs to be a link. Do you have any ideas how to make it happen?

Comment: Yes, do as I said previously and split both social media buttons into different containers. Separate the top portion from the bottom and add some `margin` to get the spacing you desire.

Comment: Alright, I'll try - thanks!

Comment: I can do it in a second.

Comment: It would be great if you could! I'd need a bit more than a second

Comment: Hmm, please note that it works fine on width below 979px. That's weird...

Comment: Nevermind - I managed to fix it! Is was as simple as removing float:left from ".facebook-btn, .twitter-btn" classess and adding margin-left: -3px...

Comment: An anchor (a) tagged element should not have another 'clickable' element like a button inside it.